# How to convert UNIX Timestamp to PST in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time

I am getting Date & Time in UNIX Timestamp.
So wanted to convert it to "America/Los_Angeles" Timezone in dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS format.

How to do this in PHP ?

e.g: 
Input: 1345014000
Output: 15-08-2012 00:00:00

Answer (score 5):

The `date_default_timezone_set` function can be used to set the current timezone within PHP. You need only call this once per file, as all calculations from then onwards will be done using that timezone. It accepts all valid timezone names, such as the one you mentioned.

The `date` function on the other hand, accepts a string explaining the format, and the timezone you wish to be converted. A full list of formatting options can be found at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Usage in your situation would be as follows:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
$str=date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$timestamp); //Where $timestamp is the timestamp to be converted
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the timestamp to a string, you can use the [following function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

and you need to set your timezone (either on server level in php.ini or on script level) by the [following function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php):

```
bool date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )
```

which would be called as followes:

```
date_default_timezone_set ("America/Los_Angeles");
$yourDateString = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $yourTimeStamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
DATE("Y-m-d H:i:s",$unix_timestamp);
```

I get my tymestamp from a database, so actually my code is:

```
echo DATE("d/m/Y H:i", $row['lastlogin']);
```

Answer (score 0):

using DateTime:

```
<?php
$input = '1345014000';
$oDate = new DateTime('@' . $input, new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

echo $oDate->format('d-m-Y H:i');
?>
```

If your default Timezone is set to LA, you could omit the second argument for DateTime. Else, you can use the timezone of your choice and as such create multiple $oDates for different timezones, should you want to do that